# libcurl with x86-64-w64-mingw32-g++ undefined reference. g++ works fine

Tags: linux, g++, cross-compiling, libcurl, mingw-w64

I am trying to cross-compile simple C++ program for Windows using libcurl and Linux.
I am using the following code:

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB curl_example.cpp -o e -lcurl`

However, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccNXyMyw.o:curl_example.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccNXyMyw.o:curl_example.cpp:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccNXyMyw.o:curl_example.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccNXyMyw.o:curl_example.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I include curl like this:
`#include <curl/curl.h>`

And I've tried every suggested solution to the problem I could find. Also I have to note, that if I use g++, it works fine:

`g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB curl_example.cpp -o e -lcurl`

What could be the issue?

Comment: So did you compile and install libcurl for the x86_64-w64-mingw32 architecture?

Comment: I am afraid I did not. Is there any special way for doing that?

Comment: Yes. Dowload libcurl sources. Crosscompile libcurl. Install libcurl in the crosscompilator paths  - the library and include files. This is exactly what cross-compilation is about - you can't link libcurl compiled for linux with application compiled for windows. You have to build and prepare libcurl compiled for windows. Ok, good luck! I'll cross fingers. ; )

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that now. If I succeed please post an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @KamilCuk well, any hint on Crosscompile libcurl for mingw32 architecture stage? Can't find info on that.

Comment: It looks like it uses configure scripts to compile [from here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html). [Configure scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) have long history, but you [should be able](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html) to crosscompile with most autotools setups.

Comment: @KamilCuk i've managed to finally compile it! Hope this will work. Thank you very much. You can post an answer if you want so I could mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to compile curl for the x86_64-w64-mingw32, as @KamilCuk suggested. In order to do that, I configured with

`./configure --build x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32`