# How to cross-compile with curl on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: c++, ubuntu, winapi, libcurl

I want to compile this source code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "I am compiled with curl";
}
```

I am compiling on Ubuntu 22.04, *but targeting Window 7 and Windows 10*.  As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107758/libcurl-with-x86-64-w64-mingw32-g-undefined-reference-g-works-fine), I must configure curl.
I downloaded the curl package on this address: https://curl.se/download/curl-7.86.0.tar.gz

I extract it, and entered the command `./configure --build x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --without-ssl` into the directory.
Here are the end of the output:

```
configure: amending tests/server/Makefile
configure: amending tests/libtest/Makefile
configure: amending docs/examples/Makefile
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  Host setup:       x86_64-w64-mingw32
  Install prefix:   /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32
  Compiler:         x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
   CFLAGS:          -O2 -pthread
   CPPFLAGS:        
   LDFLAGS:         
   LIBS:            -lbcrypt -ladvapi32 -lcrypt32 -lwldap32 -lws2_32

  curl version:     7.86.0
  SSL:              no      (--with-{openssl,gnutls,nss,mbedtls,wolfssl,schannel,secure-transport,amissl,bearssl,rustls} )
  SSH:              no      (--with-{libssh,libssh2})
  zlib:             no      (--with-zlib)
  brotli:           no      (--with-brotli)
  zstd:             no      (--with-zstd)
  GSS-API:          no      (--with-gssapi)
  GSASL:            no      (libgsasl not found)
  TLS-SRP:          no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         POSIX threaded
  IPv6:             enabled
  Unix sockets:     enabled
  IDN:              no      (--with-{libidn2,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  Code coverage:    disabled
  SSPI:             no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     
  ca fallback:      
  LDAP:             enabled (winldap)
  LDAPS:            enabled
  RTSP:             enabled
  RTMP:             no      (--with-librtmp)
  PSL:              no      (libpsl not found)
  Alt-svc:          enabled (--disable-alt-svc)
  Headers API:      enabled (--disable-headers-api)
  HSTS:             no      (--enable-hsts)
  HTTP1:            enabled (internal)
  HTTP2:            no      (--with-nghttp2, --with-hyper)
  HTTP3:            no      (--with-ngtcp2, --with-quiche --with-msh3)
  ECH:              no      (--enable-ech)
  WebSockets:       no      (--enable-websockets)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP LDAP LDAPS MQTT POP3 RTSP SMB SMTP TELNET TFTP
  Features:         AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM UnixSockets alt-svc threadsafe
```

This is the error I have when I try to compile:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -lws2_32 -lwininet -s -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wno-write-strings -fno-exceptions -fmerge-all-constants -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

    1 | #include <curl/curl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

If I add the argument `-lcurl`, I have the error: `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I have also insalled packages

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

What should I am supposed to do? Someone can tell me which commands I should execute to compile this snip?

**EDIT:** To clarify my problem, I can't use g++ because I have other includes like:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
```

It's the reason why I use mingw (maybe a bad reason but I don't know how to compile with theses libraries on Ubuntu using g++).

Comment: That's a compiler error, not a linker error. The compiler cannot find the header file `<curl/curl.h>`. You have done the `configure` step; now, have you done the `make` and `make install` steps as well (some more info [here](https://curl.se/docs/install.html))? After that, the curl header should be somewhere like `/usr/include` and the compiler should be able to find it.

Comment: Why do you use mingw on Ubuntu? Are you aware of GCC in Ubuntu packages?

Comment: i am currently referring to this guide [here](https://curl.se/docs/install.html), trying to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded the curl package

Why do you apply the poor Windows steps to your Ubuntu? Just install libcurl dev package:

```
sudo apt install libcurlpp-dev
```

> What should I am supposed to do? Someone can tell me which commands I should execute to compile this snip?

Don't use MinGW on Ubuntu. Install GCC from Ubuntu packages. I assume, it's already installed if you have installed any dev package.

Comment: `sudo apt install build-essentials`  Is a prerequisite. I get the impression OP has already completed that step though.

Comment: `libcurl-dev` does not exists. Please could you indicate me the commands with gcc? I use i686-w64-mingw32-g++  because I want to use the executable on Windows 7 and 10 as a portable executable.

Comment: You have installed it already, as for your question. So, just use g++ to compile your code: g++ file.cpp -lcurl

Comment: I just add an edit to clarify the situation.

Comment: If you even compile that code with mingw, you will not be able to run it on your Ubuntu.

Comment: i think the OP is trying compile it for "windows" not ubuntu, if i am getting the question right and your solutions seems to be targeted for compiled application to run on ubuntu itself.